# Should I use a server to do multiple services

Tags: performance

I want to ask, I want to build a DNS server, mail server, and DHCP server and possibly an SQL server in my office, the client to this server is less than 100. So, if I have a server, say, with RAM 12 GB , and CPU 3GHz, should I cram all the roles in one server or should  I use virtualization and separate the SQL server and the other server?

Comment: Whether this question gets re-opened or not (and my personal feeling is that, after your edits, it's a decent best-practice question), it already has some good answers, and you should accept one of them (or a better one if it comes along soon) by clicking on the "tick" outline next to it.  This is local etiquette, and drives the SF reputation system both for you and for the author of the answer; please accept my apologies if you already know this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to have one main service per server. Why?

- If something goes wrong it will be easier to troubleshoot
- It will be easier to tune for different workloads (e.g. two services may have different suggestions for the same kernel tunable)
- If your business grows and you need to be [PCI-DSS compliant](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3-1.pdf) you'll already be on your way to satisying 2.2.d:

> Implementing only one primary function per server to
>   prevent functions that require different security levels
>   from co-existing on the same server

and 2.2.1.a:

> Select a sample of system components and
>   inspect the system configurations to verify that only one
>   primary function is implemented per server.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes

Long answer: It depends entirely on how many clients do you expect each service to be handling.

If you have an SQL server that is used by an application to its limits, so that it hardly catching up with its tasks, you do not want the machine to do other non-trivial tasks. But I guess you would be aware of this if this was the case, so most likely, in your specific case, there will not be any problem to use it for all the services you have mention.

DNS servers are quite efficient, so unless you are going to serve public requests for very famous domains, you should be just fine.

SQL servers need most of the resources usually. It depends on applications that use them. From your list, it is SQL server that you have to be careful with.

Mail servers are rarely demanding on resources, so again, unless you expect to be processing hundreds of thousands of emails daily, feel free ti include.

DHCP server - no problems here either.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer, so basically it depends on how much resource the service will take isn't it? so is it wise to cram many services that doesn't use too much resource on one server ? thank you once again

Comment: It is no problem. We had a server that acts as a cache DNS server, a Web server, an SQL server, a Mail server, an FTP server, and a Git server. As our application grew, there was a problem with disk I/O on SQL server, so we moved the SQL server to a dedicated machine while leaving the rest of services on the original machine. So, as you can see, it is no problem as long as you monitor how much resources are needed for each service.